# Java Как использовать 2 или 3 версии slf4j в своей программе?

Tags: java, исключения, maven, логирование, slf4j

собираю проект через maven, использую Windows8 с NetBeans. У меня есть код:

```
           try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newStr))){
                
                String mimeType = tika.detect(is); //определяем mimeType нашего документа
                metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);//устанавливаем mimeType
                
                AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); 
                ContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1); 
                parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc); //разбор файла на части

           } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException ex) {

                System.out.println("Exception of Tika");

           } catch (Throwable th) {
               System.out.println(th.getMessage());
                th.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("catch");
```

При выполнении операции на строчке - parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc). Программа не может обработать файл и начинает переходить в catch. Раньше она всегда заходила в первый catch из-за exception, которые бросала сама Tika, после того как я добавил библиотеку какую-то или что-то поменял в pom.xml, она не ловит exception от tika, а идет во 2-ой catch и ловит другой exception. Я прочитал th.printStackTrace() и увидел такое сообщение:

```
org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:131)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupTable(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:263)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.readLookupList(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:231)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable.read(GlyphSubstitutionTable.java:80)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.readTable(TrueTypeFont.java:353)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:173)

...
```

После я залез в mav dependency:tree и увидел, что некоторые версии slf4j конфликтуют между собой. Определенные библиотеки хотят использовать старую версию, а не ту которую я указываю в своем pom.xml.

---

Мой новый pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>StackExp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <tika>1.2</tika>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <!-- catch-throwable для отлавливания exception-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.codearte.catch-exception</groupId>
            <artifactId>catch-throwable</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- commons-lang3: для замера времени-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- jdom: для чтения файла task.xml-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tika-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>     
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- New1-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- New2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.28</version>
        </dependency>


        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-debugger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ome</groupId>
            <artifactId>bio-formats</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Helper's dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gagravarr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-tika</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
               
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackexp.Parser</mainClass>
                       
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                      
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.stackexp.Parser</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Например в mvn dependency:tree я могу увидеть:

```
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.intellij:annotations:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.28)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.28:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  +- (org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-tika:jar:0.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1)
[INFO] |  +- org.tallison:jmatio:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.28)
[INFO] |  +- com.epam:parso:jar:2.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0.22)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0.19)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.pdfbox:preflight:jar:2.0.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0.22)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.16:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.pdfbox:xmpbox:jar:2.0.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0.22)
[INFO] |  +- org.tallison:isoparser:jar:1.9.41.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  +- com.rometools:rome:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.rometools:rome-utils:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  +- com.github.junrar:junrar:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.9:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.28:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.25)
[INFO] |  |  +- (net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.28)
[INFO] |  +- edu.ucar:grib:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (edu.ucar:cdm:jar:4.5.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.28)
```

Полное сообщение этого дерева можно увидеть в файле - https://dropmefiles.com/SMjrP

---

И поэтому такой вопрос, как можно использовать 2 или 3 библиотеки этого slf4j, или как можно дать этим подключенным библиотекам нужные им версии библиотеки slf4j? Вообще как можно решить такую ситуацию конфликта версий? Подскажите какие есть подходы в решении такой задачи. Заранее спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Как думаете значит надо сделать вместо двух (tika-app 1.2 и 1.25), один, например 1.25?

Comment: Да, конечно. Само по себе `omitted for conflict` - не обязательно проблема. Проблемой это стает только если в изменениях в API нет обратной совместимости. tika 1.2 и 1.25 не считаются мавеном конфликтными (так как у них група отличается) и он оставляет их обе. И они тянут за собой ворох почти одинаковых библиотек разных версий

Comment: Это я сделал. Оставил tika-app 1.25. Но при этом все равно, как другим библиотекам, которые например хотят slf4j 1.7.7, при подключенном 1.7.28, дать то, что они хотят. 
@RomanKonoval : Как решить такое?

Comment: Если коротко, то две разных версии использовать нельзя. Можно делать две вещи 1. выбирать нужную версию когда есть конфликт 2. изменить версии библиотек, которые порождают конфликты (т.к. зависят транзитивно от конфликтующих версий) чтоб конфликт версий не приводил к проблемам (т.е. версии были совместимы по API).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537459/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-spi-locationawarelogger-log вот здесь подход описан вцелом.

Comment: Ну например я выбираю slf4j 1.7.28. При этом какая-то библиотека хочет использовать 1.7.6. Первый вариант отпадает, пробую второй, значит мне надо зайти внутрь библиотеки и как мне изменить версию библиотеки?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123287/discussion-between-evendie-and-roman-konoval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов решения данной проблемы: сначала попробуем убрать повторяющиеся и ненужные библиотеки. Например в моем pom.xml повторялся tika-app. Затем я выполнил команду:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=slf4j
```

И увидел дерево зависимостей. В нем было показано какие jar (с какой версией) использует в библиотеку slf4j. Самой нужной для меня библиотекой была `org.apache.Tika:tika-app (v1.25)`. Внутри она использовала:

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar    
org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar
org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar
```

Я привел их к одной версии 1.7.28, которую хотел иметь tika-app. После этого стал смотреть на другие библиотеки, которые хотели версию меньше 1.7.28. Для того, чтобы убрать конфликт версия я для каждой такой библиотеки добавил такую зависимость в pom.xml:

например для

```
[INFO] |  +- org.tallison:jmatio:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.28)
```

я добавляю в pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tallison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmatio</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Так делаю для каждой библиотеки, которая хочет иметь slf4j с версией меньше, чем моя указанная в pom.xml.